# Concurrency problems between GLThread and HeapWorker

Tags: android, opengl-es, garbage-collection, android-ndk, swig

My problem concerns the use of a native NDK library exposed to Java through Swig in the Android os.

The native library is an OpenGLES engine. During the life of the app, the java code may create instances of native classes with which we will feed the engine. What bothers me is that these classes may get garbage collected on the Java side. When this is the case, it is another thread (the HeapWorker) than the main engine thread (the GLThread) that will delete the object through the swig-generated finalize method. This causes some concurrency problems in the native engine where objects could be used during their deletion by the HeapWorker thread.

Is it possible to:

1 - Customize the Garbage collector in some way that it would synchronize with the GLThread ?

2 - Run the finalizers GLThread ?

3 - Lock the GLThread during garbage collection ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While GLThread executes some JNI that access a Java object **jo**, JNI will hold local reference to **jo**, and therefore garbage collector will not touch this object. But if your native code keeps pointers to some Java objects (*object*) across JNI calls, garbage collection will become problematic. Unfortunately, not only GC will be broken; your code will not run on ICS or JB.

Comment: My code runs perfectly on ICS, garbage collection works. The only problem remaining is that concurrency problem, so we can let the c++ objects unregister themselves from anything they are registered to (as pointers) in the engine when they are deleted (GC'd). But this has to be done in the proper thread.